# Trailing spaces allowed in foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Issue:** SQL Server allows trailing spaces to be added to a foreign key!

This behaviour of course leads to various unwanted behaviour in the application. How can this be stopped?

**Example:** Two tables in a 1:n relationship:

```
create table products 
(
    pid nvarchar(20) primary key
;)

create table sales 
(
    pid nvarchar(20) references products(pid), 
    units int
);
```

Now insert primary key `'A'`:

```
insert into products (pid) values ('A');
```

Now insert foreign keys:

```
-- 'A' is accepted, as expected:
insert into sales (pid, units) values ('A', 23); 

-- 'B' is declined, as expected:
insert into sales (pid, units) values ('B', 12); 

-- 'A ' (with a trailing space)
-- This is ACCEPTED, but of course this is NOT EXPECTED !! 
insert into sales (pid, units) values ('A ', 12);
```

Comment: Check your `ANSI_PADDING` setting. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56876

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I don't want that trailing spaces to be removed. I only want that `'A'`and `'A '`are treated differently!

Answer (score 2):

A second issue is that this is really hard to detect since :

```
    select pid from sales group by pid
```

returns only one value: A in your example

Here is a trick to help detect the issue:

```
    select pid from sales group by binary(pid)
```

This returns 2 rows: A and A (with trailing space)

Cheers,

Comment: Yeah thank you! The issue is also in that case, that the expression `'A'='A '` is true! Therefore, of course, these two elements group together to one element. Meanwhile I've learned from that and all tables have a check constraint. No trailing spaces allowed. For keys, also leading spaces are disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just plain don't want to allow trailing spaces:

```
create table sales 
(
    pid nvarchar(20) references products(pid), 
    units int,
    constraint CK_sales_pid CHECK (RIGHT(pid,1) <> ' ')
);
```

Otherwise, you need to realise that this is not just a single "unexpected" situation. The SQL Standard says that when there are two strings with unequal lengths, the shorter string is first padded with spaces to make the lengths equal, before comparisons occur.

Comment: Yes thank you. In theory, I would like to have that the expression `('A'='A ')` returns false and not true. But it seems this is deeply rooted in SQL Server and cannot be changed. (or?) Thus, a check constraint like you suggest is a pragmatic solution. BTW, Oracle behaves differently, and since I was working with Oracle many years, I'm "shocked".

Comment: Oracle's behavior is different for foreign keys, but same for comparison. `select 'true' from dual where 'x' = 'x ';` returns one row, `'true'`.